# MFC about handle message

Tags: c++, mfc

I reference to [about handle messsage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/598/Windows-Message-Handling-Part-2?fid=789&fr=11#xx0xx), and practice to impletement it

I want to send user define message such as WM_MESSAGE, from about dialog use bottom click to send message (SendMessage) for main dialog recieve. 
In main dialog(HandleMessageDlg.cpp and HandleMessage.h), I create button to show about dialog, 
In about dialog(AboutDlg.cpp and AboutDlg.h), I ceate button to sent WM_MESSAGE

Implement as follow:
HandleMessageDlg.cpp

```
// HandleMessageDlg.cpp : 實作檔
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HandleMessage.h"
#include "HandleMessageDlg.h"
#include "AboutDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// 對 App About 使用 CAboutDlg 對話方塊

class CAboutDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

// 對話方塊資料
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV 支援

// 程式碼實作
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton1();
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialog(CAboutDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CAboutDlg::OnBnClickedButton1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CHandleMessageDlg 對話方塊




CHandleMessageDlg::CHandleMessageDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CHandleMessageDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CHandleMessageDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CHandleMessageDlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_MESSAGE (WM_MESSAGE, OnHandleMessage)
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CHandleMessageDlg::OnBnClickedButton1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CHandleMessageDlg 訊息處理常式

BOOL CHandleMessageDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // 將 [關於...] 功能表加入系統功能表。

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX 必須在系統命令範圍之中。
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        CString strAboutMenu;
        strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // 設定此對話方塊的圖示。當應用程式的主視窗不是對話方塊時，
    // 框架會自動從事此作業
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // 設定大圖示
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // 設定小圖示

    // TODO: 在此加入額外的初始設定

    return TRUE;  // 傳回 TRUE，除非您對控制項設定焦點
}

void CHandleMessageDlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialog::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

// 如果將最小化按鈕加入您的對話方塊，您需要下列的程式碼，
// 以便繪製圖示。對於使用文件/檢視模式的 MFC 應用程式，
// 框架會自動完成此作業。

void CHandleMessageDlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // 繪製的裝置內容

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // 將圖示置中於用戶端矩形
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // 描繪圖示
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialog::OnPaint();
    }
}

// 當使用者拖曳最小化視窗時，
// 系統呼叫這個功能取得游標顯示。
HCURSOR CHandleMessageDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}

LRESULT CHandleMessageDlg::OnHandleMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    TRACE(L"wParam %d, lParam %d", wParam, lParam);
    return 0;
}

void CAboutDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: 在此加入控制項告知處理常式程式碼
    GetParent()->SendMessage(WM_MESSAGE, 0, 0);
}

void CHandleMessageDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: 在此加入控制項告知處理常式程式碼
    CAboutDlg AboutDlg;
    AboutDlg.DoModal();
}
```

[HandleMessageDlg.cpp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/car7htjsu7weybm/HandleMessage.cpp)
HandleMessage.h

```
// HandleMessageDlg.h : 標頭檔
//

#pragma once

// CHandleMessageDlg 對話方塊
class CHandleMessageDlg : public CDialog
{
// 建構
public:
    CHandleMessageDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);    // 標準建構函式

// 對話方塊資料
    enum { IDD = IDD_HANDLEMESSAGE_DIALOG };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV 支援
    afx_msg LRESULT OnHandleMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// 程式碼實作
protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;

    // 產生的訊息對應函式
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam);
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton1();
};
```

[HandleMessage.h](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tqa0al1p44xqe90/HandleMessageDlg.h)
AboutDlg.cpp

```
// AboutDlg.cpp : 實作檔
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HandleMessage.h"
#include "HandleMessageDlg.h"
#include "AboutDlg.h"


// AboutDlg 對話方塊

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(AboutDlg, CDialog)

AboutDlg::AboutDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(AboutDlg::IDD, pParent)
{

}

AboutDlg::~AboutDlg()
{
}

void AboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(AboutDlg, CDialog)    
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// AboutDlg 訊息處理常式
```

[AboutDlg.cpp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vg515u2fufgsspe/AboutDlg.cpp)
AboutDlg.h

```
#pragma once

#define  WM_MESSAGE WM_USER+0x100

// AboutDlg 對話方塊

class AboutDlg : public CDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(AboutDlg)

public:
    AboutDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // 標準建構函式
    virtual ~AboutDlg();

// 對話方塊資料
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };



protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV 支援

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

[AboutDlg.h](https://www.dropbox.com/s/udlh491rjsln8gb/AboutDlg.h)
Now I have problem with

what parameter is relation to WM_MESSAGE, is wParam or lParam, may i 
   if(lParam == WM_MESSAGE) or if(wParam == WM_MESSAGE)

thanks

Comment: One of the applications I maintain uses MFC. Sure, it works, but if you have the opportunity: get away from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `CHandleMessageDlg::` in front of the definition of `OnHandleMessage()`, as follows:

```
//      v v v v v v v v v v  Notice the addition of "CHandleMessageDlg::" here
LRESULT CHandleMessageDlg::OnHandleMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    TRACE(L"wParam %d, lParam %d", wParam, lParam);
    return 0;
}
```

Does that work?

Comment: thank you, add CHandleMessageDlg:: in code, it will be compilered, but no message as "wParam %d, lParam %d" in output window

Comment: i forget dismark ON_MESSAGE (WM_MESSAGE, OnHandleMessage), and it will work. Another problem is how will decide recv message is WM_MESSAGE, 
EX, if(lParam == WM_MESSAGE) ?

Comment: @user1753112 Because of the line `ON_MESSAGE (WM_MESSAGE, OnHandleMessage)`, you already *know* that `OnHandleMessage()` is being called in response to `WM_MESSAGE`.  Therefore, neither argument (`wParam` or `lParam`) contains the message number.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so i must use wParam and lParam to case my sending message, use SendMessage(WM_MESSAGE, 0, 1) and SendMessage(WM_MESSAGE, 0, 2), then in handleMessage function use switch(lParam) { case 1: TRACE(L"I get message 1"); break; case 2: TRACE(L"I get message 2"); break}; isnt it?

Comment: @user1753112 That's exactly what `wParam` and `lParam` are for in the case of user-defined messages.